# NSView frame set by means other than -setFrame: following autoresizing

Tags: cocoa, nsview, autoresizingmask

My application loads a window and buttons within that window from a XIB file via `NSWindowController`. In `-windowDidLoad`, I programmatically set the frames of the buttons based on the size of the window, which can be variable depending on which buttons are visible). Autoresizing masks are set appropriately in the XIB for these buttons. The problem is that when the window actually appears, the buttons appear as though no autoresizing was applied.

In debugging this issue, I subclassed `NSButton` and overrode `-setFrame:` to print the frame (`[self frame]`) after calling super's `-setFrame:`. Using this I observe that the frame is set twice: first by my programmatic layout code (call this frame A), and later once Cocoa adjusts the window size based on user preferences (applying the autoresizing mask, setting the frame to B). These frames all look correct.

However, when the window appears it is as if the latter `-setFrame:` call had no lasting effect – the frame of the button is now back to A. This is verified by breaking in the debugger and printing the frame - the autoresize frame updates have been reverted, but `-setFrame:` was never called again.

Any ideas as to why I might be seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It will initially happen when the `superview` is being sized by `setFrameSize:` but more often happens when the `superview`'s `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded` method is called, which in turn calls the view's `resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:`. You can override this by either subclassing the `NSView`, in your case `NSButton`, and overriding `resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:` with an empty method like

```
- (void)resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:(NSSize)oldSize {}
```

However, you can also solve the problem more elegantly by stating that you don't want your `NSView` resized by the auto layout system. You can do this by:

```
[<id> setAutoresizingMask:NSViewNotSizable];
[<id> setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
```

where `<id>` would be the instance of your `NSView`, so perhaps if you had a outlet

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *myButton;
```

then you would set

```
[self.myButton setAutoresizingMask:NSViewNotSizable];
[self.myButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
```

followed by calling `setFrame:` with the frame you want. The first line states that the view is not sizable, while the second states that the mask should be considered a constraint by the auto layout system. Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**
Sorry, for some reason I read your problem as the reverse of what I suggested, that auto layout is overriding your changes. However, you want to know the opposite. If you are using `setAutoresizingMask:` have you tried `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES`? It would also be helpful if you could post a minimal working example.